# Aligning graphics within wrapfigure

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, wrapfigure

I'm trying to create a biography section for a list of authors am crammed for space. So when declaring the wrapfigure to provided text wrapping around each author's tessellated bio photo, I need to reduce the number of lines wrapped.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section*{Biography}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{L}{25mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Alpha} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{25mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Beta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{L}{25mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Gamma} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{25mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Delta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\end{document}
```

However it appears that the author images are not centered with the text wrap boundary. I would like to align the images at the top of the boundary to make the word wrapping as tight as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there are not floats, I suggest you the set of plain TeX macros provided by `insbox`, which does a better job in this case. It defines a `\InsertBoxL{number of non-shortened lines at the beginning of the paragraph}{object inserted}[optional: number of supplementary shortened lines (in case TeX makes a wrong calculation of necessary sorter lines)]` command, and a similar `\InsertBoxR`. I added an example code to fine-tune the vertical position of the inserted graphics, playing with the optional arguments of `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
\section*{Biography}

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}[-1]
\textbf{Author Alpha} \Blindtext[1][13]

\InsertBoxR{0}{\raisebox{0pt}[17.9mm]{\includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}}[-1]
\textbf{Author Beta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}[-1]
\textbf{Author Gamma} \Blindtext[1][13]

\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}[-1]
\textbf{Author Delta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This work for me as well, and is much cleaner. Although for my eventual case I still needed the other method to be able to tweak the vertical position. But TIL about insbox.

Comment: @ruffsl: I slightly modified the code for inserting the second graphics, to show how the vertical position can be adjusted with the optional arguments of `\raisebox`.

Comment: This does not seem to work with `itemize`.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Pygmalion: I've already seen it work with a list environment. Could you post a small complete code illustrating your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, but it's not as robust or automated as I'd like, so am still looking for a better solution. By simply adding `\vspace{-5mm}` within the wrapfigure before the includegraphics, we can shift up the bio image's vertical alignment manually.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section*{Biography}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{L}{25mm}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Alpha} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{25mm}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Beta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{L}{25mm}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Gamma} \Blindtext[1][13]

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{R}{25mm}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \includegraphics[width=25mm,height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Author Delta} \Blindtext[1][13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, that is exactly the standard procedure with the current implementation of the wrapfigure package, afaik. it's just not a very good/clean (in terms of TeX layout automation) solution, since this vspace will vary for each picture with caption and even then, it doesn't always work. for pictures of the same dimensions with no caption, it's a passable solution, though.