# Adjust intextsep for wrapfigure only

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

Related questions:

[Wrap figure vertical alignment of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365753/wrap-figure-vertical-alignment-of-text)

[Too much space around wrap figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/too-much-space-around-wrap-figure/111397#111397)

[wrapfigure environment vspace above figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286232/wrapfigure-environment-vspace-above-figure)

[Aligning graphics within wrapfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391616/aligning-graphics-within-wrapfigure)

[Why is my custom wrapfig environment messed up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266418/why-is-my-custom-wrapfig-environment-messed-up/266431#266431) and its follow-up question [wrapfig vs intextsep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278091/wrapfig-vs-intextsep)

In the questions mentioned above, several solutions are offered to eliminate the whitespace inserted above `wrapfigure` environments. The most obvious way is to set `\intextsep` to zero globally. Unfortunately that also affects the spacing around normal figures, which look rather terrible with 0 padding.

The new environment defined in [Why is my custom wrapfig environment messed up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266418/why-is-my-custom-wrapfig-environment-messed-up/266431#266431) does not solve that problem, as was already pointed out in the follow-up question.

Now neither `\begingroup` or `{\setlength{\intextsep}\begin{wrapfigure}...}` (as suggested in the follow-up) work well for me, as I am using wrapfigures right above `\paragraph{}` most of the time which produces errors. Additionally, I am using a lot of itemized lists, as I'm mainly using TeX to write lecture notes / summaries, reducing as much text as possible to keypoints. So these solutions would generate a set of new problems, which I'd like to avoid.

The solution of using `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` is how I've dealt with the issue up until now. Although that does work, it is a pain to add it to every wrapfigure. The option of inserting the `vspace` into the `wrapfigure` directly is also subpoptimal, as the images vary in size and ratio quite drastically. Additionally, `vspace` is ignored if the width of the wrapfigure is specified as `{0}` (automatic sizing to image / tabular width).

So I've come to the (potentially wrong) conclusion, that the best option would be to set `\intextsep` to zero *globally* but only for wrapfigures (not figures).  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any answer that explained how I could achieve this.

Is there any way to do this - adjusting `\intextsep` *only* for wrapfigures?

I'll add a MWE copied from one of my summaries, in case that helps:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=13.6pt,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{quoting,polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\usepackage{multirow,
            tabularx,booktabs,array,
            multicol,
            wrapfig,float,subcaption}
        \setlength{\multicolsep}{3.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}
        \setlength{\floatsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} %default: \setlength{\floatsep}{12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} 
        \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt} %default: \setlength{\textfloatsep}{20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt} 
        \setlength{\intextsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} %default: \setlength{\intextsep}{12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}

    \usepackage[skip=2pt,figurename=Abb.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
        \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
            \captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=it}
                \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=2pt,font=scriptsize,labelfont=it}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*}
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*}

\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow{}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.92\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-6.png}
\caption{Basissymptome nach Kolsterkötter, 1992; 2012}
   %\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}  --> a vspace I inserted before I set \intextsep to 0; this figure still has sufficient padding (why is unclear to me though)
\end{figure}
Diese Rückkehrhemmung ist bei Schizophrenen gestört \arr Aachen-Studien mit Covert Orienting of Attention Task; Gouzoulis-Mayfrank (2004, 2006, 2007): Gemessen wurde die RT beim Auffinden bestimmter Objekte an der alten Position \arr Schizophrene sind \emph{schneller} 

Interpretation: Schizophrene können verschiedene Filter nicht anwenden, weshalb sie immer wieder auf basale Information zurückkehren müssen \arr Rückkehrhemmung bei Schizophrenen

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
   %\vspace{-\baselineskip}   --> this wrapfigure is now where I want it with \intextsep 0
\centering
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-8.png}
\caption{Moritz, 2006}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Gedächtnisfehler \& Korrektheitskonfidenz} Studie von Moritz (2006): Bild wird gezeigt, dann entfernt; Frage: Erinnern sie sich an ...? Wie sicher sind sie sich?
\begin{itemize}
\item Gesunde Kontrollen waren sich nicht signifikant sicherer bei korrekten Antworten \arr gesehene Objekte erkennen bzw. nicht gesehene als solche bezeichnen
\item Schizophrene Patienten sind sich viel sicherer, wenn die Antwort \emph{inkorrekt ist} \arr signifikanter Unterschied
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Falsche Korrektheitskonfidenz \arr Gedächtnisfehler
    \item Alles Nicht-Wahn Inhalte in Studie
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Basissymptome als Verlaufstest}
\paragraph{Hypothese:} Overinclusion als "symptomnahe Basisstörung" ist bei akuter Psychose besonders ausgeprägt \& wird im Verlauf schwächer \arr \textbf{Overinclusion:} Irrelevante Konzept-Merkmale werden integriert \arr Übereinschluss in Konzepte; Begriffe, Sachverhalte, Figuren, Schemata. 
   %\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}  --> this figure now is way too close to the text above with \intextsep 0
\begin{figure}[hb]
\begin{subfigure}{0.52\linewidth}
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-11.png}
\caption{Maercker, 1987; Kawohl, 2010}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-12.png}
\caption{Maercker, 1987; Kawohl, 2010}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which compiles as:

[image]

Note: I'm using XeLaTeX, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to set the `\intextsep` globally, but *only* for the `wrap figure` environemnt would be to use `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
```

The *before*

> [image]

and *after* the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` is applied:

> [image]

### Notes:

- In the MWE below I commented out your manual adjustment to `\setlength{\intextsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}`.
- You can uncomment the `\showthe\intextsep` to see the effect.
- The `demo` option was used on the `graphicx` package as I don't have the figures you were including.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=13.6pt,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}


\usepackage{quoting,polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\usepackage{multirow,
            tabularx,booktabs,array,
            multicol,
            wrapfig,float,subcaption}
        \setlength{\multicolsep}{3.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}
        \setlength{\floatsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} %default: \setlength{\floatsep}{12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} 
        \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt} %default: \setlength{\textfloatsep}{20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt} 
        %\setlength{\intextsep}{0.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt} %default: \setlength{\intextsep}{12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}

    \usepackage[skip=2pt,figurename=Abb.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
        \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
            \captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=it}
                \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=2pt,font=scriptsize,labelfont=it}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*}
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=2pt,leftmargin=*}

\newcommand{\arr}{$\rightarrow{}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.92\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-6.png}
\caption{Basissymptome nach Kolsterkötter, 1992; 2012}
   %\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}  --> a vspace I inserted before I set \intextsep to 0; this figure still has sufficient padding (why is unclear to me though)
\end{figure}
Diese Rückkehrhemmung ist bei Schizophrenen gestört \arr Aachen-Studien mit Covert Orienting of Attention Task; Gouzoulis-Mayfrank (2004, 2006, 2007): Gemessen wurde die RT beim Auffinden bestimmter Objekte an der alten Position \arr Schizophrene sind \emph{schneller} 

Interpretation: Schizophrene können verschiedene Filter nicht anwenden, weshalb sie immer wieder auf basale Information zurückkehren müssen \arr Rückkehrhemmung bei Schizophrenen

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
   %\vspace{-\baselineskip}   --> this wrapfigure is now where I want it with \intextsep 0
\centering
%\showthe\intextsep% <-- uncomment to see the change
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-8.png}
\caption{Moritz, 2006}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Gedächtnisfehler \& Korrektheitskonfidenz} Studie von Moritz (2006): Bild wird gezeigt, dann entfernt; Frage: Erinnern sie sich an ...? Wie sicher sind sie sich?
\begin{itemize}
\item Gesunde Kontrollen waren sich nicht signifikant sicherer bei korrekten Antworten \arr gesehene Objekte erkennen bzw. nicht gesehene als solche bezeichnen
\item Schizophrene Patienten sind sich viel sicherer, wenn die Antwort \emph{inkorrekt ist} \arr signifikanter Unterschied
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Falsche Korrektheitskonfidenz \arr Gedächtnisfehler
    \item Alles Nicht-Wahn Inhalte in Studie
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Basissymptome als Verlaufstest}
\paragraph{Hypothese:} Overinclusion als "symptomnahe Basisstörung" ist bei akuter Psychose besonders ausgeprägt \& wird im Verlauf schwächer \arr \textbf{Overinclusion:} Irrelevante Konzept-Merkmale werden integriert \arr Übereinschluss in Konzepte; Begriffe, Sachverhalte, Figuren, Schemata. 
   %\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}  --> this figure now is way too close to the text above with \intextsep 0
\begin{figure}[hb]
\begin{subfigure}{0.52\linewidth}
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-11.png}
\caption{Maercker, 1987; Kawohl, 2010}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[frame,width=0.99\linewidth]{Path2-Pictures/3-12.png}
\caption{Maercker, 1987; Kawohl, 2010}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are my personal hero! :D

Comment: It does not work though: once set, it remains to this value until the document end. So subsequent figures are affected… At least that’s what I see in my document (I’ve tried the above one but the figure at the end are on the next page).

Comment: @Archange: If you don't want it document wide, then apply the setlenght setting only before the reqiured figure: `{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%` (note leading `{`), followed by `\begin{wrapfigure} ... \end{wrapfigure}}` (note extra trailing `{`). The additional `{` and `}` create a group and keep your change to `\intextsep` local to that group.

Comment: I want it document wide for `wrapfigure`, but not for `figure`. Currently after the first `wrapfigure` (well actually right before it of course), `intextsep` is set to 0 globally, and does affect subsequent `figure`.

Comment: @Archange: Sorry an busy next few days, so can't look at this issue right now. Please post a new question. It will be helpful if you include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: OK, I’m a bit busy too so I’ll do that when I get some time to make a MWE and post a link here.

Comment: Hey @PeterGrill, I’ve finally got some time to do this (mostly because it hit me again ^^): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682412/56823

Answer (score 0):

In an [answer on a separate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682415/72011) (which includes an example), @Ulrike Fischer suggested the following code for the preamble which avoids setting `intextsep` globally and thereby avoids changing spacing on normal figures.

```latex
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\WF@putfigmaybe{\lower\intextsep}{}{}{\fail}%
\AddToHook{env/wrapfigure/begin}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother
```