# Adjust intextsep for wrapfigure only (continued)

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure, vertical-spacing

In [Adjust intextsep for wrapfigure only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415398/56823), @Peter Grill provided an option to modify `\intextsep` for `wrapfigure` only and leave `figure` unaffected.

However it does not really work for me: as soon as a `wrapfigure` happens in the document, subsequent `figure` are affected too, so the setting obviously “leaks” into the environment. I have asked about this in comments to his answer, and [he asked me to open a new question about my issue with a MWE,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415398/adjust-intextsep-for-wrapfigure-only#comment1658657_436852) so here we are.

Here is a MWE showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

Some text initially.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Notice how it is properly spaced above and below.}
\end{figure}

Now let’s add some wrapped figure.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}

Asperiores est aspernatur dolorum sit. Expedita dolorum voluptatem iste. Eum
laudantium ipsum ea omnis aut fugiat harum quis. Ut repellendus est incidunt.
Esse cum a omnis. Explicabo odio inventore asperiores ex ad. Quidem quia
voluptatibus incidunt. Est dolores est perferendis dicta ullam inventore.
Deleniti ab enim accusantium sint qui voluptatem. Qui sed assumenda adipisci ad
reiciendis velit magnam. Nobis aut nihil quae est. Molestiae possimus quo quia
magnam et dicta odio. Est quia quasi rem vel omnis eveniet. Quasi rerum tempore
velit consequatur consequatur consectetur veritatis. Sed blanditiis et sed
libero consequatur sed. Numquam et ipsam rem. Sed facere aut ipsam. Tenetur
rerum et sed est aspernatur ipsa quia. Hic error ut maiores doloremque quas.
Error eum quae rerum modi debitis.

And now, a figure again.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Notice how it is \emph{not} properly spaced above and below.}
\end{figure}

See the issue ?

\end{document}
```

And the produced result:
[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well `BeforeBeginEnvironment` (now the `env/wrapfigure/before` hook) doesn't work as it is before the group created by wrapfig and so affects following figure environments.

Using the `env/wrapfigure/begin` hook with

```
\AddToHook{env/wrapfigure/begin}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
```

doesn't work either as it resets `\intextsep` to early and this confuses the placement of the wrapfigure:

[image]

Resetting the value in the `env/wrapfigure/after` doesn't work either.

You could try to reset it before the next figure but on the whole I think one need to patch internal of wrapfigure here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\WF@putfigmaybe{\lower\intextsep}{}{}{\fail}%
\AddToHook{env/wrapfigure/begin}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some text initially. 

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Notice how it is properly spaced above and below.}
\end{figure}

Now let’s add some wrapped figure. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}

Asperiores est aspernatur dolorum sit. Expedita dolorum voluptatem iste. Eum 
laudantium ipsum ea omnis aut fugiat harum quis. Ut repellendus est incidunt. 
Esse cum a omnis. Explicabo odio inventore asperiores ex ad. Quidem quia 
voluptatibus incidunt. Est dolores est perferendis dicta ullam inventore. 
Deleniti ab enim accusantium sint qui voluptatem. Qui sed assumenda adipisci 
ad reiciendis velit magnam. Nobis aut nihil quae est. Molestiae possimus quo 
quia magnam et dicta odio. Est quia quasi rem vel omnis eveniet. Quasi rerum 
tempore velit consequatur consequatur consectetur veritatis. Sed blanditiis 
et sed libero consequatur sed. Numquam et ipsam rem. Sed facere aut ipsam. 
Tenetur rerum et sed est aspernatur ipsa quia. Hic error ut maiores 
doloremque quas. Error eum quae rerum modi debitis. 

And now, a figure again.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Notice how it is \emph{not} properly spaced above and below.}
\end{figure}

See the issue ?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Though, could you explain what the patch command does? I’m not familiar with that one.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `lthooks` has nothing regarding `patchcmd`, but I’ve found great explanations here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/56823.

Comment: Oops, that would be etoolbox, and the real question is the source for `\WF@putfigmaybe` (from wrapfig).